# css @font-face not woking in FF

Tags: css, fonts

My custom font face is not being applied in FF. This does work in Coda(my development app). And also in Safari...

The CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: MyScriptFont;
  src: url('fonts/giddyup.ttf');
}
/* IE9+ */
@font-face {
  font-family: MyScriptFont;
  src: url('fonts/giddyup.eot');
    }
    #tagCommon {
    font-family: 'MyScriptFont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 52px;
    position:relative;
    padding-top:22px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="tagCommon"></div>
```

The site is http://tntplants.site11.com/. When you type letters into the top box on the right it should be in giddyup script font on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap your CSS declarations around - put the TTF one after the EOT one. Eg

```
/* IE9+ */
@font-face {
  font-family: MyScriptFont;
  src: url('fonts/giddyup.eot');

@font-face {
  font-family: MyScriptFont;
  src: url('fonts/giddyup.ttf');
}
    }
    #tagCommon {
    font-family: 'MyScriptFont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 52px;
    position:relative;
    padding-top:22px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All the major browsers have decided to go their own way with font formats that they choose to support:

- Internet Explorer only supports EOT
- Mozilla browsers support OTF and TTF
- Safari and Opera support OTF, TTF and SVG
- Chrome supports TTF and SVG.

So, to have a full and proper support you need to follow a certain structure when declaring the face-face:

**CSS FONT-FACE e.g.**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GiddyupWebRegular';
    src: url('giddyup-webfont.eot');
    src: url('giddyup-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('giddyup-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('giddyup-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('giddyup-webfont.svg#GiddyupWebRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

See the [working example here!](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/76169930/stackoverflow/question/10727272/giddyup-demo.html)

Download the generated CSS with the fonts and CSS [here!](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/76169930/stackoverflow/question/10727272/webfontkit-20120523-164327.zip)

**The above links** were generated using a font-face code generator, you upload the font and the code pops out for you:

[Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)

For more information, read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@font-face) from the MDN.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is to switch out your font stack to one from Font Squirrel

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Name';
    src: url('Name.eot');
    src: url('Name.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('Namet.woff') format('woff'),
        url('Name.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('Name.svg#Name') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`MyScriptFont` is not the same as `'MyScriptFont'`.

Change your font-family declaration in `#tagCommon` to `MyScriptFont` or change it in `@font-face` to `'MyScriptFont'`.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyScriptFont';
  src: url('fonts/giddyup.ttf');
}
/* IE9+ */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyScriptFont';
  src: url('fonts/giddyup.eot');
}
#tagCommon {
    font-family: 'MyScriptFont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 52px;
    position:relative;
    padding-top:22px;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work, but good point none the less. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I really should have tested first. I hope the info helped regardless.